# Row widget is requiring a textDirection

Tags: flutter

Using Row or Column widget is resulting in the following error:

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Horizontal RenderFlex with MainAxisAlignment.start has a null textDirection, so the alignment cannot be resolved.
'package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart':
Failed assertion: line 462 pos 18: 'textDirection != null'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Row file:///C:/Users/...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Unless I provide the Row/Column widget with a textDirection property, then it would work. Here is an example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyWidget());
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      // textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      children: [
        BlueBox(),
        BlueBox(),
        BlueBox(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I don't understand why the code doesn't work unless I add the textDirection property.
Note: I am following this doc https://flutter.dev/docs/codelabs/layout-basics

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is: why should I add a textDirection property to get this to work?
[The docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/codelabs/layout-basics) didn't specify that a textDirection is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row/Row.html):

> The textDirection argument defaults to the ambient Directionality, if
> any. If there is no ambient directionality, and a text direction is
> going to be necessary to determine the layout order (which is always
> the case unless the row has no children or only one child) or to
> disambiguate start or end values for the mainAxisAlignment, the
> textDirection must not be null.